# WCF named pipes on POS Ready 2009

Tags: .net, wcf, named-pipes

We're building a touch screen kiosk application that will run on Windows POS Ready 2009.  We need to ensure that the application is always running, so we've built a watchdog process that our application pings periodically, and if the watchdog doesn't get a ping, it'll start/restart the app - a fairly standard idea.

Our application is WPF and requires .net 4 (which is all fine) and we chose to use WCF named pipes for the inter-process communication.  This now seems like a bad idea because I don't think WCF using named pipes is natively supported on POS Ready 2009 and I can't find an where on the internets how to install/configure support for it.

Any one know if/how I can run my application with WCF named pipes on POS Ready 2009.

EDIT: My bad - file under "Too Stupid to Live".  Thanks for your answer Chris, you are completely right and it does work perfectly on POS Ready 2009.  Other deployment issues had me flummoxed.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you are now doubting named pipe support on this platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any hands on experience with POS Ready 2009, but Microsoft's product web site claims "Full Win32 compatibility" for Win32 applications out-of-the-box, and support for .NET 4 as an option. If the Win32 Named Pipe APIs are present as this implies, then the WCF NetNamedPipeBinding ought to work.